# CXF : No method was found for the WSDL operation

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, cxf

I have been struggling with this for 2 days now so I must ask for help.

I have a multifaced Maven project using Spring.

```
GesAction
-ihm
-metier
-dao
-entite
-ws
```

The whole project compile, no problem with mvn:install.

The problem lies in the ws module : I may have a problem with CXF configuration : When I deploy the module on my tomcat (v7) I have these warning for each operations on my WSDL :

```
déc. 29, 2015 10:02:56 AM org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean initializeWSDLOperations
AVERTISSEMENT: No method was found for the WSDL operation {http://ws.gesaction.interiale.fr}Authentification.
```

But of course these operations are included in the WSDL... It drives me mad.

Here are the configuration files:

ws-context.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd       
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context       
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd   ">

    <context:component-scan base-package="fr.interiale.gesaction.ws.impl"/>
    <context:annotation-config />  
    <import resource="classpath:metier-context.xml"/>  
    <import resource="cxf-context.xml" />

</beans>
```

the cxf-context.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xmlns:soap="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd 
        http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap 
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd 
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

<!--    <bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/> -->

    <jaxws:endpoint 
        id="interialActionSocialAuthentification" 
        implementor="fr.interiale.gesaction.ws.InterialActionSocialAuthentification"
        endpointName="tns:InterialActionSocialAuthentificationPort"
        serviceName="tns:InterialActionSocialAuthentificationService" 
        address="/InterialActionSocialAuthentificationPort"
        xmlns:tns="http://ws.gesaction.interiale.fr"
        wsdlLocation="wsdl/interialactionsocialauthentification.wsdl">
    </jaxws:endpoint>

</beans>
```

And now the WSDL :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tns="http://ws.gesaction.interiale.fr" 
    name="interialactionsocialauthentification"
    targetNamespace="http://ws.gesaction.interiale.fr" 
    >

    <wsdl:types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <import namespace="http://ws.gesaction.interiale.fr" schemaLocation="interialactionsocialauthentification_schema1.xsd" />
        </schema>
    </wsdl:types>


    <wsdl:message name="Authentification">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Authentification"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="AuthentificationResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:AuthentificationResponse"></wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:message name="remiseANullTokenResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:remiseANullTokenResponse">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="remiseANullToken">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:remiseANullToken">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="AuthentificationParTokenResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:AuthentificationParTokenResponse">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="AuthentificationParToken">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:AuthentificationParToken">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="Exception">
        <wsdl:part name="Exception" element="tns:Exception">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:portType name="InterialActionSocialAuthentification">

        <wsdl:operation name="Authentification">
            <wsdl:input name="Authentification" message="tns:Authentification"></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="AuthentificationResponse" message="tns:AuthentificationResponse"></wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="Exception" message="tns:Exception"></wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>

        <wsdl:operation name="remiseANullToken">
            <wsdl:input name="remiseANullToken" message="tns:remiseANullToken">
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="remiseANullTokenResponse" message="tns:remiseANullTokenResponse">
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="Exception" message="tns:Exception">
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="AuthentificationParToken">
            <wsdl:input name="AuthentificationParToken" message="tns:AuthentificationParToken">
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="AuthentificationParTokenResponse"
                message="tns:AuthentificationParTokenResponse">
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="Exception" message="tns:Exception">
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:binding name="InterialActionSocialAuthentificationServiceSoapBinding"
        type="tns:InterialActionSocialAuthentification">
        <soap:binding style="document"
            transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="Authentification">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document" />
            <wsdl:input name="Authentification">
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="AuthentificationResponse">
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="Exception">
                <soap:fault name="Exception" use="literal" />
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="AuthentificationParToken">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document" />
            <wsdl:input name="AuthentificationParToken">
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="AuthentificationParTokenResponse">
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="Exception">
                <soap:fault name="Exception" use="literal" />
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="remiseANullToken">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document" />
            <wsdl:input name="remiseANullToken">
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="remiseANullTokenResponse">
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="Exception">
                <soap:fault name="Exception" use="literal" />
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="InterialActionSocialAuthentificationService">
        <wsdl:port name="InterialActionSocialAuthentificationPort"
            binding="tns:InterialActionSocialAuthentificationServiceSoapBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/gesAction-ws" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

The XSD refered in the WSDL:

```
<xs:schema 
    xmlns:tns="http://ws.gesaction.interiale.fr" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
    elementFormDefault="unqualified" 
    targetNamespace="http://ws.gesaction.interiale.fr">

  <xs:element name="Authentification" type="tns:Authentification"/>
  <xs:element name="AuthentificationParToken" type="tns:AuthentificationParToken"/>
  <xs:element name="AuthentificationParTokenResponse" type="tns:AuthentificationParTokenResponse"/>
  <xs:element name="AuthentificationResponse" type="tns:AuthentificationResponse"/>
  <xs:element name="remiseANullToken" type="tns:remiseANullToken"/>
  <xs:element name="remiseANullTokenResponse" type="tns:remiseANullTokenResponse"/>
  <xs:element name="utilisateur" type="tns:utilisateur"/>

  <xs:complexType name="Authentification">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg0" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg1" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg2" type="xs:boolean"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="AuthentificationResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:utilisateur"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="utilisateur">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="idutilisateur" type="xs:decimal"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="nom" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="prenom" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="login" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="mdp" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="profil" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="token" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="tokenTimestamp" type="tns:timestamp"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="maritalStatus" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="profilSummary" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="birthday" type="xs:dateTime"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ville" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="codePostal" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="mobileNumber" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="email" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="civilite" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="timestamp">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="nanos" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="remiseANullToken">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="arg0" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="remiseANullTokenResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="return" type="xs:boolean"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="AuthentificationParToken">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg0" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="AuthentificationParTokenResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:utilisateur"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="Exception" type="tns:Exception"/>
  <xs:complexType name="Exception">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="message" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I can deployed this properly and send some SOAP request with SOAP GUI tool.

But I cannot have this working :'(

If anything is needed to help for understanding I will edit my post with it.

Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact I was missing the CXF code generation ...This part generate the service interface with all the required annotations (@WebService etc ...)

Comment: If you haven't forgotten, can you expand on your solution?

Comment: You need the maven operation that triggers the code generation (look for anything about the maven plugin : <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>)

Answer (score 1):

You need to map endpoint method with "Authentification" so that spring will detect and execute it once requested from soap client.

In spring we do it as follows :-

@Endpoint
public class MyEndpoint{

```
@PayloadRoot(localPart="Authentification", namespace=SOME_TARGET_NAMESPACE)
public @ResponsePayload MyResponse myMethod(@RequestPayload MyRequest request){

}
```

}

Add `<context:component-scan base-package="package-name" />` in spring-config.xml

Comment: First : thank you very much for helping. So for the <context:component-scan base-package="package-name" /> it is alreayd in my ws-context.xml which is a Spring config file. Then about the @PayloadRoot anotation. In the project I don't know why but there are no such annotation. Apparently It's all done via Autowired controllers

Comment: Ok, you might have followed some different approach for spring configuration, that's fine. But you need to put mapping some where in application using xml or annotation so spring will know which java method to execute for the given request local part. Just give it a try by putting @PayloadRoot annotation above the method which you want to get executed once request is made.

Comment: Will do : feedback asap.

Comment: Also be sure to match target namespace in @PayloadRoot

Comment: I am sorry but I have no @EndPoint Classes, it seems to be all done via CXF framework and the cxf-context.xml that I have shared... :'(